# I'm having problems running eas build

Tags: javascript, error-handling, expo, eas

how are you? I'm having problems running eas build. It says export failed and the error is "Cannot find module 'expo/bin/cli.js". Could you help me with the solution. I tried things like using a different version of node or expo, but I still get the errors. Here is a screenshot of what happened, thank you all.

Image of error

[image: 1]

I would like to understand the error, fix it, and be able to use the expo updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the installation instructions?
https://docs.expo.dev/build/setup/

Especially `eas build:configure`

If you installed it with yarn, you should run it like `yarn eas update`, because it's not global.

Comment: Hello, how are you? Thanks for the tip, the problem was really simple and I was so focused on one part that I forgot to do the simple. I just deleted the file `eas.json` and ran the command `eas build:configure` to generate a new one. I tried again to run `eas update` and it worked. Thank you for taking the time to help me.